# ASP.NET Core Plaintext benchmark conundrum

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying to reproduce the [impressive plaintext throughput that Techempower measures for ASP.NET Core](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r17&hw=cl&test=plaintext).

[In this article Ben Adams claims](https://www.ageofascent.com/2019/02/04/asp-net-core-saturating-10gbe-at-7-million-requests-per-second/) that the value given there is requests per second, so that would be 7 million requests per second then.

The Techempower results claim a million requests per second for an Azure D3v2 machine.

I [cloned the Techempower test application](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/tree/master/frameworks/CSharp/aspnetcore/Benchmarks) and deployed it on such a machine (more precisely a DS3_v2, not sure if that's the same).

I then used [loader.io](https://loader.io) to throw requests at the plaintext endpoint of the app and I only get 10000 requests per second.

I don't think it's loader's fault as I get proportionally smaller performance when using smaller machines.

The release is with optimizations obviously, and it does run with Environment=Production. It's using .NET Core 2.2.

I also tried deploying on Linux, but on via App Services which provide only smaller machine sizes (but is easier to do), and in those sizes there's no large difference in performance when compared to Windows.

So why don't I get the awesome performance that Techempower measured? Their result is a hundred times faster!

Comment: I would assume that loader.io simply does not have such a high client-side concurrency. TechEmpower runs the plaintext test with up to 16,384 concurrent clients. It would be somewhat unusual to expect that loader.io does that too.

Comment: I would argue with paragraph 6 in the question: If it's loader, I would expect faster machines not to lead to more processed requests.

Comment: Well, if you do 2 requests at the same time and each takes 10 ms, then you get 200 requests per second. If these requests now take 15 ms because the machine is slower, then you will get 133 requests. Compare that to 5 requests at the same time at 500 vs. 333 requests. – So you will still see an effect from slower machines. The server can still handle more of them, they just take longer.

Comment: Oh, that's very true. Then it could indeed be loader.